# Code erases previous month record while updating current month record

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Using 11gR2, windows 7 client machine. I need to update the table missing_volume (below), where I need to calculate the estimated_missing column. The calculation of estimated_missing column for current month needs previous month numbers (as commented inside the code below). I want the output like the first table. Notice the records start from January, hence estimated_missing for January can't be calculated, but for the the rest of the months it can be done by simply changing 'yr' and 'mnth' (commented inside the code towards the end).

```
yr      mnth        location    volume      actual_missing    expected_missing  estimated_missing

2013    January     loc1        48037       24                57                    
2013    February    loc1        47960       3660              53                24
2013    March       loc1        55007       78                57                28
2013    April       loc1        54345       72                58                77
```

The code:

```
UPDATE missing_volume g
    SET
        g.estimated_missing = 
        (
            SELECT

                CASE
                    -- If the previous month actual_missing number is less than 2 times than that of the previous month expected_missing number,
                    -- then for current month: 
                    -- estimated_missing = previous_month(actual_missing/volume)*current_month(volume)
                    -- 
                    -- Else, for current month:
                    -- estimated_missing = previous_month(estimated_missing/volume)*current_month(volume)

                    WHEN (NVL(p.actual_missing, 0)/NVL(p.expected_missing, 1)) <= 2.0
                        THEN ROUND(NVL(p.actual_missing, 0)*( NVL(g.volume, 0)/NVL(p.volume, 1) ), 0)
                    ELSE
                        ROUND(NVL(p.estimated_missing, 0)*( NVL(g.volume, 0)/NVL(p.volume, 1) ), 0)
                END                     

            FROM 
                (
                    SELECT
                        yr,
                        mnth,
                        loc_cd,
                        volume,
                        actual_missing,
                        expected_missing,   
                        estimated_missing
                    FROM missing_volume
                    WHERE yr = TRIM(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2), 'YYYY'))   -- For February it is -4, for March it is -3, for April it is -2
                    AND UPPER(mnth) = UPPER(TRIM(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -2), 'Month')))  -- For February it is -4, for March it is -3, for April it is -2
                )p
            WHERE g.yr = TRIM(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'YYYY'))   -- For February it is -3, for March it is -2, for April it is -1
            AND UPPER(g.mnth) = UPPER(TRIM(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'Month')))  -- For February it is -3, for March it is -2, for April it is -1
            AND g.volume IS NOT NULL
            AND TRIM(p.location) = TRIM(g.location)                     
        );
```

The code does calculate correct number for 'estimated_missing' as I run the code for each month, but the problem is while updating the current month it also erases the record for previous month. E.g. as can be seen below, after I updated April the column only has the record for April, previous month record is gone, similarly updating March removed February, etc. I can't understand why it's happening!! Here is the output I get:

```
yr      mnth        location    volume      actual_missing    expected_missing  estimated_missing

2013    January     loc1        48037       24                57                    
2013    February    loc1        47960       3660              53                
2013    March       loc1        55007       78                57                
2013    April       loc1        54345       72                58                77
```

Will appreciate if any body can explain why it's happening (I mean where is the flaw in the code) and how to get the desired output (first table).

Thanks

Comment: There is no WHERE clause on your UPDATE statement - therefore, you're updating all rows in MISSING_VOLUME.  You might also check to see if there are any triggers defined on MISSING_VOLUME which might be affecting this.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: I did not follow your reply, there is a where clause in my code which is intended to just update the current month estimated_missing. Please note I am not updating missing_volume. Also there is no trigger on any column of this table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a where clause for your statement. 
At the moment that WHERE clause is *inside* the braces. Your statement basically is:

```
UPDATE missing_volume g
SET
    g.estimated_missing = 
    ( [...]
    ); -- no where clause here
```

What you **need** is this:

```
UPDATE missing_volume g
SET
    g.estimated_missing = 
    ( [...]
    )
WHERE g.yr = TRIM(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1), 'YYYY'));
```

Haven't tested it myself but this should only update the row for the current month.